# Connecting to SQL Server Docker container from another docker container (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker

I am going insane here. I can connect from SQL Server Management Studio and from Visual Studio SQL browser. Looking at the logs from the SQL Server container, there isn't even a connection from the C# api.

I am getting every random error possible, from sql40, to sql44, to kerberos error (I am not using kerberos), to server/guest error (I am using SQL Server authentication), I have no idea what else it can be.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost,1433;Database=newDBName;User=sa;Password=mypassword;Trusted_Connection=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;Encrypt=false;"
},
```

Docker compose:

```
# docker-compose up -d
# docker-compose down

version: '3.8'
networks:
    localdev:
        name: localdev
services:
    db-server:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
        container_name: mssqlRT
        environment:
          - SA_PASSWORD=mypassword
          - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
        networks:
          - localdev
        volumes:
          - sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql        
        ports:
          - "1433:1433"
    serviceapi:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}serviceapi
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: src/ServiceAPI/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
        - db-server
        networks:
          - localdev
        volumes:
          - ./etc/wait-for.sh:/app/wait-for.sh
        ports:
          - "5001:80"
volumes:
    sqlvolume:
```

Thanks in advance

I have tried localhost, 0.0.0.0, container name, I get a different error to each one of it.

```
container name: kerberos
localhost: sql 40
0.0.0.0  sql 44
```

Comment: Have you tried `Server= mssqlRT,1433;` yet? From a networking perspective Docker containers are essentially little Linux VMs, so `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1` all refer to the container itself. Since SQL Server isn't running inside the API container there's nothing listening on port 1433 for it to connect to.

Comment: Aside... choose one of `User=sa;Password=mypassword;` or `Trusted_Connection=true;`. The former is using SQL Logon authentication with a username or password, the latter uses Windows/Active Directory/Kerberos authentication with the credentials under which the current process is executing.

Comment: I've removed the "Trusted_Connection" property, and changed "User" to "User Id". So far so good. Will get back with more information later on. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's working fine with the changes i mentioned in the comment above! Thanks